# In WordPress I use a Plugin for Appointment Booking (amelia), why the javascript doesn't fetch the selector with .find() function from jQuery,

Tags: jquery, selector

On this Site: aufschalten.ch
I try to implement a javascript for the use of geonames.org data, for the form fields PLZ and Ort.
Outside of the Plugin it does work. See on the Start Page Bottom. But I can't find how to make the Script fetching the Selectors of the Fields I created in the Plugin "amelia" Appointment Booking System.
Use on aufschalten.ch Startpage: chose Service -> weiter (button) -> Chose Date and Time -> weiter (button) -> now the form is shown, and there the Field PLZ and Ort are not trigered by the Script.
The Plugin has an option to add custom fields. In the Text Fields I created, I can put HTML Code. And so I implement two Input Fields according the fields i created for Testing on the Start Page (https://aufschalten.ch). But the Script is not working. I tried to use find() `jQuery('.el-input').find('#PLZ')` and other combination of selectors an find with no success so far.

I'm implementing the Javascript in the Header with a Wordpress Plugin "custom css and JS"

More Testing I'm doing here: https://codepen.io/scribbi/pen/poyNjZm

Why the Script is not fetching the selectors in the Plugin App even if use find()?
I'm using this simple Fields added in amelia Plugin Backend as Text Fields containing custom HTML Code:

```
PLZ


Ort
```

``

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.el-input').find('#PLZ').bind('keyup change', function (e) {
    if (jQuery(this).val().length > 3) {
        var ort = jQuery('.el-input').find('#Ort');
        jQuery.getJSON('http://secure.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?username=aufschalten.ch&country=CH&callback=?', { postalcode: this.value }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.postalcodes.length && response.postalcodes[0].placeName) {
            ort.val(response.postalcodes[0].placeName);
        }
      })
    } else {
        jQuery('.el-input').find('#Ort').val('');
    }
 });
});
``
```